# How to return records which date = now every X months in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP cron which runs once every day which I need to fetch records from tableA which match this month's day number (ie: 5th), but only every X months.

Each tableA's record as a tag_id which relates the a record in tableB which holds the X month interval:

tableA

```
id | title | tag_id | date
---------------------------
1  | foo   | 1      | 2018-01-05 00:00:00
2  | bar   | 1      | 2018-12-05 19:00:00
3  | cat   | 2      | 2017-11-05 10:00:00
4  | car   | 3      | 2016-08-05 11:11:11
```

tableB

```
id | label | months
-------------------
1  | text  | 1
2  | anim  | 3
3  | veh   | 6
```

tableA.tag_id = tableB.id

Which the given data, i'd like a query which would use tableB.months to figure out if today is the correct interval day for the record with the matching tag_id and return the records. For today (5th of Jan), the query would return all 4 of the records.

I'm not asking for someone to write the query, I just can't get my head around how to manipulate date data to get it to work like this.

I'm starting to think something to do with Modulo and ensuring its == 0 based off tableB.months

this NEARLY does the job:

```
MOD(DATEDIFF(NOW(), tableA.date), (tableB.months * 30)) = 0.
```

But it's a bit quirky, thanks to the months being different lengths.

Comment: So we could call tableb tags

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, currently thinking this might do the job         MOD(DATEDIFF(NOW(), tableA.date), (tableB.months * 30)) = 0

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to get the difference in months. Use `DAY()` to get the day of month:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
  ON  b.id = a.tag_id
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), DATE(a.date)) % b.months = 0
WHERE DAY(a.date) = DAY(NOW())
```